# Looking to obtain file information using Google Cloud functions.

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I am attempting to gather some data on some files that I am receiving, I am looking for File size, number of records, date file received.  These are .CSV files.  At this point I have a function that will take a file that lands in the Bucket and pick up this file and move it to a new bucket.  I am assuming that there are some sort of commands that can get this metadata from the file I am already grabbing.  Ultimately I would like to write these results to a file, or table or an e-mail every time this file arrives.

A note this is my very first Google cloud project and I have absolutely zero Java coding background. here is the code I have so far:

Any advice is appreciated.

```
exports.CopySomewhereElse = (event, callback) => {
  const file = event.data;
  const context = event.context;

const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');

 // Creates a client
  const storage = new Storage();

  const srcBucketName = file.bucket;
  const srcFilename = file.name;
  const destBucketName = 'somewhere_else';
  const destFilename = file.name;

  // Copies the file to the other bucket
 storage
    .bucket(srcBucketName)
    .file(srcFilename)
    .copy(storage.bucket(destBucketName).file(destFilename))
    .then(() => {
      console.log(
        `gs://${srcBucketName}/${srcFilename} copied to gs://${destBucketName}/${destFilename}.`
      );
    })
    .catch(err => {
       console.error('ERROR:', err);
    });

  callback();
};
```

Comment: I think I found an NPM package that might do what I am looking for.. it is at the following site: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gcp-metadata  
I was able to install the package... but I have no idea how to test it or use it...

Comment: sorry for commenting on different question (Sending emails using sendgrid and Google cloud platform) here - don't want to be exposed too much with following message  -  i am in private beta with product that does EXACTLY this - if interested - contact me via LinkedIn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the solution for this:

It was as easy as File.size  and File.TimeCreated

```
exports.CopySomewhereElse = (event, callback) => {
  const file = event.data;
  const context = event.context;

  const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');

  // Creates a client
  const storage = new Storage();

  const srcBucketName = file.bucket;
  const srcFilename = file.name;
  const destBucketName = 'somewhere_else';

  const destFilename = file.name;
  const filesize = file.size;
  const FileName = file.name;
  const FiletimeModified = file.LastModified;
  const FileID = file.ID;
  const FiletimeCreated = file.timeCreated


  //const fileContentDisposition = file.contentDisposition;



  // Copies the file to the other bucket
  storage
    .bucket(srcBucketName)
    .file(srcFilename)
    .copy(storage.bucket(destBucketName).file(destFilename))
    .then(() => {
      console.log
                (
                    `gs://${srcBucketName}/${srcFilename} copied to gs://${destBucketName}/${destFilename}.|${filesize}|${FileName}|${FiletimeCreated}|${srcBucketName}`
                )
            //  (
            //      `${filesize}`
            //  )
    ;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('ERROR:', err);
    });

  callback();
};
```

Comment: You can also have a look at the official documentation of the [NodeJS Client Library for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.6.x/), specifically, you can find information about the available metadata in the [`getMetadata()` method](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.6.x/File#getMetadata).

Comment: Also, whenever you are able to (usually 2 days after you originally posted the question), please accept your own answer in order for the community to identify that this question was solved. Thanks!